# Import FBX Maya animation with gravity and directional force into Three JS

Tags: animation, three.js, export, maya, fbx

I'm trying to figure out how to capture an animation that I made in Maya using gravity and and two directional forces to pull an avocado apart. I'm currently using three objects and the animation is working just how I'd like it to. Importing into Three js however has been the issue. Can I capture all of the keyframes all at once? How can I export the keyframes for the aggregate object into three js for a single animation that will be played on a JS event? I've shared a gif of the current animation. Any tips/suggestions welcome.

[image]